# Ошибка при запуске SWT приложения в IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, eclipse, swt

Вобщем есть пустой проект в `IDEA` к нему я подключаю `swt.jar` но при попытке запуска приложения выдает ошибку:

> cannot access org.eclipse.swt.SWT bad class file:
>   org/eclipse/swt/SWT.class(org/eclipse/swt:SWT.class) class file has
>   wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0 Please remove or make sure it
>   appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

В проекте я использую Java 1.6.

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: SWTTestTask
Bundle-SymbolicName: SWTTestTask
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.0
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64.source;bundle-version="3.6.2"
Import-Package: org.eclipse.jface.viewers,
 org.eclipse.swt.widgets,
 javax.activation
```

В чем может быть проблема?

**P.S**: В Eclipse IDE  все запускается нормально.

Comment: В Idea: Settings - Java Compiler - Target bytecode version какая версия?

Comment: Там вообще никакая не была установлена. Щас поставил 1.6 и выдает другую ошибку: Error:java: javacTask: source release 1.8 requires target release 1.8

Comment: Так, эту ошибку я поправил.  теперь другая Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access

Comment: Возможно эта [ссылка](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Why_do_I_get_an_invalid_thread_access_exception%3F) поможет.